# паронимы. "рыбий" и "рыбный" (и еще "советник" и "советчик")

Tags: паронимы

У меня два вопроса. Первый: откуда пошло различие в написании слов "советник" и "советчик"? Смысл же одинаковый. Второй вопрос: в каких случаях мы говорим рыбий, а в каких рыбный?

Comment: Вам бы и надо два вопроса задать. Здесь не принято два разных вопроса обсуждать в одной теме. Но в данном случае предлагаю здесь отвечать на второй, поскольку он понятен, а первый переформулировать в другом вопросе, ибо он некорректен по постановке. Советник и советчик -это разные слова,,с разным смыслом, думаю, Вы это понимаете. Поэтому смысл вопроса не совсем ясен.

Answer (score 2):

**Разницу в значении можно посмотреть в словаре:**

СОВЕТЧИК,  1. Тот, кто советует, даёт советы  Мне не нужны советчики. Он мой постоянный с. 2. Со сл.: хороший, плохой  Гнев - плохой с.

СОВЕТНИК, - 1. Устар. =Советчик.  2. Название некоторых должностей, а также лиц, занимающих эти должности. С. посольства. Титулярный с. Надворный с. Тайный с.

В толковом словаре словообразовательных частиц оба суффикса (НИК и ЧИК) названы **продуктивными и регулярными**.  Суффикс НИК образует существительные с    **общим отношением**  к мотивирующему слову, а ЧИК  называет лица, **характеризующиеся отношением** к мотивирующему слову.

Советчик - не профессия, а  разовое участие в ситуации, зависящее от компетентности лица в конкретном вопросе. Советник - это должность.

**Дополнение**

**Что же здесь не так?** Сведения из словаря Ефремовой.

Буфет - буфетчик,  водопровод - водопроводчик, зенитный - зенитчик. Суффикс ЧИК используется при образовании существительных **от различных частей речи (не только от глаголов)** , к тому же это фонетический вариант суффикса ЩИК.

Суффикс НИК более широкого профиля, но также используется при образовании **от различных частей речи (не только от имен)**: изменник, клеветник, заступник,  разлучник, сообщник, шутник, путник, двоечник. Кроме того, он образует неодушевленные существительные: задачник, чайник, малинник.  Неясно, **почему это НИК только недавно стал продуктивным?**

Кстати, как мне кажется, "советчик" в современном языке всё более приобретает **негативную окраску**: я плохой советчик, мне не нужны советчики. Этот суффикс в в большей степени может выразить **качественный признак**, чем "относительный" суффикс НИК, это чувствуется, с моей точки зрения, даже на слух.

Comment: Это сообщение заслуживало минуса, удаленного модератором. Ответ неконкретен. Подмена вопроса в лучшем случае. Разница в значениях не прояснена.

Answer (score 1):

Рыбий — притяжательное прилагательное (чей?); принадлежащий рыбе или рыбам: рыбий глаз, рыбий хвост, рыбья молодь (сравните, например: (чья?) щучья молодь) и.т.д.

Рыбный — относительное прилагательное (какой?); относящийся к рыбе, сделанный из рыбы: рыбная промышленность, рыбное место, рыбный суп, рыбные котлеты и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

**Рыбий и рыбный**. Тут все просто.

***Рыбий*** - относящийся к одной отдельной взятой рыбе или *рыбам* вообще. *Рыбий жир. Рыбий глаз, плавник. Рыбьи повадки, рыбья кость*.

***Рыбный*** - связанный с рыбой в собирательном значении: как к продукту питания или сырью для изготовления *рыбных* блюд. *Рыбный навар. Рыбный магазин. Рыбная мука.*

Часто разное прилагательное задает разный смысл. *Рыбья и рыбная чешуя* (второе - собирательное, как отход или сырье). *Рыбий* (для рыб) и *рыбный* (из рыбы) *корм*.

Есть отдельные спорные случаи. *Рыбий и рыбный* запах.

Comment: Вы назвали "рыбий" - относящимся к рыбе (что правильно), но не означает ли это, что вы толкуете рыбий как прилагательное относительное? Если да, то вам вроде как возражают.

Comment: @Morkovkin Я не вкладывал такого смысла. Но если по сути, то да, рыбий - притяжательное сейчас только по форме, из-за суффикса - и связанному с ним некоторыми особенностями словоизменения. В остальном оно давно стало обычным относительным прилагательным, как "деревянный" или там "американский".  Вот вкратце про это явление (в середине текста). http://russkiyyazik.ru/609/ В этом смысле оно ничем от "рыбный" не отличается, только разными объектами соотнесения.

Comment: @Morkovkin  (продолжение) Я видел, что два местных автора трактуют все механически и бездумно. Но спорить тут на такие скользкие темы, когда масса источников утверждает обратное, я не буду. Устал.

Comment: @Morkovkin  Ох, запутался со ссылками, потерял нужную. Ну вот здесь есть http://lingvotech.com/perehodprilag И вот http://lik-bez.com/board/morfologija/prilagatelnoe/perekhod_imjon_prilagatelnykh_iz_odnogo_razrjada_v_drugoj/32-1-0-62

Comment: Хорошо, согласен.

Answer (score 0):

**Советник и советчик.** Как уже сказал, вопрос не совсем понятен. Слова с разными значениями, вы прекрасно понимаете. 
Если же вопрос о словообразовании, то суффикс "чик" более старый и обычно связан с образованием отглагольного существительного. Т. е. советчик - от "советовать", тот кто советует.

А суффикс "ник", хоть и тоже довольно древний, но особенно продуктивным стал относительно недавно, он отвечает главным образом за образование отыменного существительного. Т. е. советник - от слова "совет" (в значении "совещательный орган", который, впрочем, стал при большевиках и законодательным, но это много позже). "Советник" исходно - член совета (военного, тайного - любого). В петровские времена должность эта стало восприниматься и как социальный статус, отсюда и всякие советники (коллежские, статские, тайные) в табели о рангах. Все они считались не просто советчиками, но и членами неких советов.

Так что разделение значения слов в общем-то понятно. А уж "откуда пошло"- ну так Божьим промыслом, наверное.